# MySQL Monitor Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, monitor

Does anyone knows any free alternative MySQL Enterprise Monitor?

I need some tool, that allows me to monitor my 3 servers with replication without having to open ssh console, and use command line.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: I asked for a solution to this issue based on Monit and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72856217/2590508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an open source tool called [MySQLMonk](http://projects.firefang.net/wiki/MySQLMonk) that can monitor replication.

Comment: broken link, downvoting

Comment: thanks for letting me know, will fix that in a few days.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to a similar question by themattreid here: [How to monitor MySQL query errors, timeouts and logon attempts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455006/how-to-monitor-mysql-query-errors-timeouts-and-logon-attempts)

He recommended looking at kontrollbase: http://kontrollsoft.com/software-kontrollbase lots of functionality and is open source.

Answer (score 1):

This Could be the tool you are looking for its called [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/monyog_feature_list.php). It does quit a neat job as far as MySQL admin operations are concerned and has a great maintenance cycle.

[MONyog - MySQL Monitor and Advisor](http://webyog.com) has separate `Replication` tab which shows **Replication topology** of all MySQL servers in your environment. 
[image]

**MONyog** has so many other features which can be helpful for DBA activities like `Find problem SQL`, `Trend analysis`, `Alerts on critical conditions` and `200+ Advisors` which makes it a complete MySQL monitoring solution.

Comment: thanks! that is good but Unlimited Users Pack    
License: $999, Support: $499, I'm still looking for something without restrictions of use.