# How to monitor MySQL query errors, timeouts and logon attempts?

Tags: mysql, profiling, monitoring, trace

While setting up a third party closed source CMS (Sitefinity) the setup doesn't create all tables and procedures necessary to run it. The software lacks a logging system itself and it made me wonder: could I trace and monitor failing SQL statements from MySQL?

This serves more than only the purpose of solving my issue with Sitefinity. More often I wonder what's send to the MySQL server, not wanting to dive into the software products or setup a debugging environment etc.

I tried JetProfiler (only performance) and looked through a [few others](http://solutions.mysql.com/solutions/?type=18), but although they monitor a lot, they don't monitor query failures, timeouts or logon attempts. Does anyone know a profiler, tracer, monitoring tool, commercial or free, that can show me this information?

Comment: You can try [Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog). It should serve the need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out Kontrollbase - it monitors just about everything you could want for MySQL servers including failed connections, aborted connections, etc. It has over 50 different graphs, performance tuning reports, advanced usage analytics reporting, security checks, and much much more. It's also 100% FREE. http://kontrollsoft.com/software-kontrollbase

There's an online demo available on the same page link listed above. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this one. Just what I needed!