# How to set Monit up to monitor MariaDB replication?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, monit

I use [Monit](https://mmonit.com) 5.27.2 and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org) 10.5.15 on my [Debian](https://www.debian.org) 11 servers.

My servers are set up in [Multi-Source MariaDB Replication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/).

Sometimes, replication stops and I am not notified. I have not seen anywhere a prepared configuration for Monit to send such alerts.

The errors are visible with the following query:

```sql
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

With those values particularly interesting:

[image: slave_io_running and slave_sql_running values]

[image: last_error value]

I have not found any way to use Monit to monitor directly the result of a SQL statement. However, it seems possible to monitor the [return code of a command](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) with versions before Monit 5.29.0 (and the output of a command after).

I can probably prepare a Bash/Shell script that will check the output of the SQL statement and then a Monit config that will send me an alert in case of issue. If I do, I will post this as an answer here. I was just wondering whether there was already a known solution to this.

I expect this to work with MySQL.

I intend to test this with those SQL queries:

```sql
STOP SLAVE;
START SLAVE;
```

Comment: recommend something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274597/store-mysql-result-in-a-bash-array-variable), and remember `show slave status` is just a SQL statement that returns a row of fixed headings like `Slave_IO_Running`, so it can be used as a key.

Comment: Thanks @danblack for your recommendation. It made sense. I tried the first option in the first answer and never got it to work. I must have a setup too specific. Also, I didn't want to install additional software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work as I expected. I did this on all servers sources of the replication.

## Installing

Here is the file `monit_replication.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash   
user="YOUR_USER"
password="YOUR_PASSWORD"

result=`echo "show slave status"|mysql -EsB --user="$user" --password="$password"`

contains_with_yes(){
        if echo "$1"|grep -i "$2"|grep -i "Yes" > /dev/null; then
                echo "$2 ok"
        else
                echo "$2 not ok"
                exit 1
        fi
}
 
contains_with_yes "$result" "Slave_IO_Running"
contains_with_yes "$result" "Slave_SQL_Running"
exit 0
```

Made this executable:

```
chmod 700 /YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_FILE/monit_replication.sh
```

Added to `/etc/monit/conf-enabled/mysql`:

```
 check program MySQL_replication with path "/YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_FILE/monit_replication.sh"
   every 120 cycles
   if status > 0 then alert
   group mysql
```

## Testing

Ran this SQL:

```sql
STOP SLAVE;
```

Restarted monit:

```
/etc/init.d/monit restart
```

Found in `/var/log/monit.log`:

```
[2022-07-04T10:46:55+0000] error    : 'MySQL_replication' status failed (1) -- Slave_IO_Running not ok
```

Received this email:

```
monit alert -- Status failed MySQL_replication

Status failed Service MySQL_replication

    Date:        Mon, 04 Jul 2022 10:46:55
    Action:      alert
    Host:        YOUR_HOST
    Description: status failed (1) -- Slave_IO_Running not ok

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

This validates the test. Restoring replication with this SQL query:

```sql
START SLAVE;
```

## Other solutions

If any simpler solution based on Monit can alert me of a replication failure on MariaDB, I would be happy to accept it as the solution to the question.